# Error while grabbing the table data from a website

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab some stock related data from the web for my project.I encountered couple of problems.
**Problem 1:**
I tried to grab the table from this site http://sharesansar.com/c/today-share-price.html
It worked but the columns aren't grabbed in order.For eg: Column 'Company Name' has values of 'Open price'. How can I solve this?
**Problem 2:**
I also tried to grab a company specific data from http://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=ADBL under 'Price History' tab.
This time I got an error while grabbing the table data.The error I got was:

```
self.data[key].append(cols[index].get_text())

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is as shown below:

```
import logging
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas


module_logger = logging.getLogger('mainApp.dataGrabber')


class DataGrabberTable:
    ''' Grabs the table data from a certain url. '''

    def __init__(self, url, csvfilename, columnName=[], tableclass=None):
        module_logger.info("Inside 'DataGrabberTable' constructor.")
        self.pgurl = url
        self.tableclass = tableclass
        self.csvfile = csvfilename
        self.columnName = columnName

        self.tableattrs = {'class':tableclass} #to be passed in find()

        module_logger.info("Done.")


    def run(self):
        '''Call this to run the datagrabber. Returns 1 if error occurs.'''

        module_logger.info("Inside 'DataGrabberTable.run()'.")

        try:
            self.rawpgdata = (requests.get(self.pgurl, timeout=5)).text
        except Exception as e:
            module_logger.warning('Error occured: {0}'.format(e))
            return 1

        #module_logger.info('Headers from the server:\n {0}'.format(self.rawpgdata.headers))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.rawpgdata, 'lxml')

        module_logger.info('Connected and parsed the data.')

        table = soup.find('table',attrs = self.tableattrs)
        rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]

        #initializing a dict in a format below
        # data = {'col1' : [...], 'col2' : [...], }
        #col1 and col2 are from columnName list
        self.data = {}
        self.data = dict(zip(self.columnName, [list() for i in range(len(self.columnName))]))

        module_logger.info('Inside for loop.')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            index = 0
            for key in self.data:
                if index > len(cols): break
                self.data[key].append(cols[index].get_text())
                index += 1
        module_logger.info('Completed the for loop.')

        self.dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(self.data)    #make pandas dataframe

        module_logger.info('writing to file {0}'.format(self.csvfile))
        self.dataframe.to_csv(self.csvfile)
        module_logger.info('written to file {0}'.format(self.csvfile))

        module_logger.info("Done.")
        return 0

    def getData(self):
        """"Returns 'data' dictionary."""
        return self.data




    # Usage example

    def main():
        url = "http://sharesansar.com/c/today-share-price.html"
        classname = "table"
        fname = "data/sharesansardata.csv"
        cols = [str(i) for i in range(18)] #make a list of columns

        '''cols = [
          'S.No', 'Company Name', 'Symbol', 'Open price', 'Max price', 
         'Min price','Closing price', 'Volume', 'Previous closing', 
         'Turnover','Difference',
         'Diff percent', 'Range', 'Range percent', '90 days', '180 days',
         '360 days', '52 weeks high', '52 weeks low']'''

        d = DataGrabberTable(url, fname, cols, classname)
        if d.run() is 1:
            print('Data grabbing failed!')
        else:
            print('Data grabbing done.') 


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Few suggestions would help.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your col list is missing an element there are 19 columns, not 18:

```
>>> len([str(i) for i in range(18)])
18
```

Besides you seem to over complicate things. The following should do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

price_response = requests.get('http://sharesansar.com/c/today-share-price.html')
price_table = BeautifulSoup(price_response.text, 'lxml').find('table', {'class': 'table'})
price_rows = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all(['th', 'td'])] for row in price_table.find_all('tr')]
price_df = pd.DataFrame(price_rows[1:], columns=price_rows[0])

com_df = None
for symbol in price_df['Symbol']:
    comp_response = requests.get('http://merolagani.com/CompanyDetail.aspx?symbol=%s' % symbol)
    comp_table = BeautifulSoup(comp_response.text, 'lxml').find('table', {'class': 'table'})
    com_header, com_value = list(), list()
    for tbody in comp_table.find_all('tbody'):
        comp_row = tbody.find('tr')
        com_header.append(comp_row.find('th').text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' '))
        com_value.append(comp_row.find('td').text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' '))
    df = pd.DataFrame([com_value], columns=com_header)
    com_df = df if com_df is None else pd.concat([com_df, df])

print(price_df)
print(com_df)
```

Comment: I still get column mismatch(Problem 1).

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. What about problem 2? Did you find any mistakes?

Comment: @Kishor It's fetching all the tickers on the first page. Add `.head(3)` to `price_df['Symbol']` such that `for symbol in price_df['Symbol'].head(3):` and you will see it terminate earlier. Then you only fetch the first 3 company information pages.

Comment: about problem 2, in that site when you scroll down you'll see a tab(having columns like About,Announcements,News
Price History, etc). Under 'Price History' tab there is a table and i want to grab that. I tried but couldnt. Can you help me?

Comment: @Kishor Grab the `div` with id `divHistory`: `.find_all('div', {'id': 'divHistory'})`. From there just grab the table, then the rows etc. like before. Try that and if you're stuck show us your code, and how/where it fails. I strongly suggest you use Chrome's inspection tool, from the right click context menu. Right click whatever you're looking for, then inspect. This will show you exactly what you need to scrape.